# Http request header and requested file name

Tags: http

It may be a stupid question but why there is no requested file name in HTTP request header? There is the host info but no file name. For ex. I'm requesting: `http://tutorial.local/newfile.php` and there aren't any info about *newfile.php* in the request header, there is only the host.

Answer (score 0):

It's in the request target (first line of HTTP/1.1 request message).